# Censor words in c

Tags: c, string, stdout, stdin

I've been working on a function which censors words. I've created this function and it works, except that it only accepts one argument. For example, when I do "./a.out test < example.txt", it replaces "test" with CENSORED in "example.txt". But when I add another one, like "./a.out test test2 < example.txt", it only replaces "test", not both "test" and "test2".

Can someone help me with my function please? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the function:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
assert(argc > 1);
char fileRead[4096];  
char replace[] = "CENSORED"; 
size_t word_len = strlen(argv[1]);

while (fgets(fileRead, sizeof(fileRead), stdin) != 0)
{
    char *start = fileRead;
    char *word_at;
    while ((word_at = strstr(start, argv[1])) != 0)
    {
        printf("%.*s%s", (int)(word_at - start), start, replace);
        start = word_at + word_len;
    }
    printf("%s", start);
}
    printf("\n");

return (0);
}
```

Comment: Why not try stepping through the code in your debugger to see what the problem is ?

Comment: Where in your code do you handle the case of replacing multiple words?

Comment: You only ever refer to `argv[1]`, not any subsequent arguments, so how could your program filter such arguments?

Comment: @Sneftel That's the problem, it only replaces one word.

Comment: @JohnBollinger This is what I'm asking. I don't know how to make it so that it uses more than 1 argument.

Comment: If you want it to be a useful tool, you should keep all the words to be censored in a file and read them in at the start. Also, rather than replacing with "CENSORED", I'd suggest "f***", "s***", etc., so that grown-ups can still tell what's being said.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put in a middle loop over `argv` elements `1` to `argc - 1`. In each iteration, it would process the line to censor the corresponding argument, just as your function now does only for the first argument.

```
int arg;

for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg += 1) {
    /* ... censor argv[arg] ... */
}
```

Note that you can then drop the `assert()`, too, as structuring the argument access that way naturally avoids accessing the `argv` array outside its bounds (if no arguments are specified, the program will run without censoring anything).

Comment: Thank you, but where should I put the for loop? I keep getting the segmentation fault error.

Comment: I have given you about as much of a hint as I can do without working your homework for you.  That would do neither you nor me any lasting good.